# Understanding the concept of conditional probability

Tags: probability

We have $X_1,..,$ indepdentnt random variables with common distribution $F(x)$ and $N$ geometric rv independent of the X_i's . Let $M = \max ( X_1,...,X_N)$. Im trying to understand the following:

[image]

Im having trouble understanding the first and third equality. This is how I view it for the third equality

$$ P(M \leq x, N=n \mid N > 1 ) = \frac{P(M \leq x, N=n, N>1 )}{P(N > 1) } = \frac{P(M\leq x \mid N=n, N>1)P(N=n, N>1)}{P(N>1)} = \frac{P(M\leq x \mid N=n, N>1) P(N=n \mid N>1)P(N>1)}{P(N>1)}= P(M\leq x \mid N=n, N>1) P(N=n \mid N>1) $$

Is this the correct reasoning? Also, the first equality follows by definition?

Comment: Please stop multiplying the duplicates on the exact same problem and try to concentrate on understanding at least some of the multiple explanations you already received about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equality is expressing the Law of Total Probability (in essence).

The event $M \leq x$ is the same as the event $M \leq x \wedge N \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ (because the second part is just "N takes a valid value"). You can then break the second part into the disjoint events $N = 1$, $N = 2$, $N = 3$, etc, and then the probability of the overall event is the sum of the individual probabilities.

The third equality is then using the normal rule of conditional probability: $P(A \wedge B) = P(A | B) P(B)$. All that is happening is that it's already conditioned on $N > 1$, but that essentially just changes the "universe" we're working in (i.e. for the sake of these probabilities, we are working in a universe where we already know that $N > 1$). So, if we ignore the $|N > 1$ part, it becomes:

$P(M \leq x \wedge N = n) = P(M \leq x | N = n) P(N = n)$

But, where we have two things we're conditioning on, that winds up being expressed as the intersection of the two events, i.e. $P((\cdot | N = n) | N > 1) = P(\cdot | N = n, N > 1)$

Comment: I dont understand why the first equality is the law of total probability. Dont we have 

$$ P( A  ) = \sum  P(A \mid B ) P(B) $$

where is the B in this case

Comment: No, because we're not summing over a bunch of conditions, we're breaking up the event (A) itself.